# Displaying and highlighting a particular line in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a webpage which should have expected to have the following properties.

1. The HTML page contains many lines of text (thousands of lines), basically a log file.
2. Upon a desired action, line which is related to the action should be highlighted and shown . (exactly the way that would happen if you click on corresponding source button of a logged variable in chrome inspect element.)

This seems to be very basic but I couldn't figure out how! May be I am missing some literary terms.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

```
$("li").each(function(i, element) {
  var li = $(element);

  if (li.text() == "Orange") {
    li.addClass("selected");

    // Get position of selected element relative to top of document
    var position = li.offset().top;

    // Get the height of the window
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    // Scroll to and center the selected element in the viewport
    $("body").scrollTop(position - (windowHeight/2));
  }
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zaknotzak/B25Ah/1/).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this. But is there any class tags in the logged source or is just one large text block?

If there are class or id tags on the html you can use javascript or jquery to do this.

```
document.getElementById('myText');
```

or in jquery

```
var element = $("#myText");
//example css changes
element.css("position","center");
element.css("color","red");
```

Then change the css style on those html elements.

Comment: Yes this way, I can highlight them, but how can I position them? like displaying the 100th line in the middle of screen and at the same time leaving all the remaining text intact.

Comment: There is css styling for position as well. Not sure what it actually is but something like. "position: center;" or you can use the margins/padding

Comment: No, position:center will only align the text of that line that it will occupy the middle-width of the screen. In my case I have to align the line in the middle-height of what is being displayed. I guess I have to manually align some lines above and below the desired line.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look into a scrollTo method/plugin with jQuery.  http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/